# The unit ball is not compact in $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

It would be a consequence of my previous question ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899324/mathbb-r-as-a-mathbb-q-vector-space-weird-what-is-a-basis-how-can-i-ri)) that was not well received (sorry for that). But since I can't construct a basis of $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb Q$-normed vector space (with usual distance $|\cdot |$), how can I prove that the unit ball is not compact ? (because a common thing is to take a sequence that has no convergent subsequence, but since there is no basis, I can write, how coul I proceed ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compactness is not a vector space property, it is purely a topological property, so you need to provide a topology (or metric, or norm) in order to detemine whether a set is compact or not.

Under the standard (Euclidian) metric, the unit ball $[-1,1]$ *is* a compact subset of $\mathbb R$.

The fact that infinitely dimensional vector spaces do not have compact unit balls is only true for vector spaces *over reals or complex numbers*.

Comment: But Riesz theorem says that if the unit ball is compact in a normed space $E$, then $E$ has finite dimension. But here $\mathbb R$ has not finite dimension over $\mathbb Q$, so it can't be compact ? (I edited my question, $\mathbb R$ is seen as a normed space over $\mathbb Q$ with the usual distance $|\cdot |$)

Comment: @Peter Riesz theorem only works for real and complex vector spaces, as far as I know.

Comment: thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Peter Typically, Riesz's lemma is stated as working for "normed vector spaces". By definition, normed vector spaces are vector spaces over real or complex numbers. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space